# Show reputation `over time` and `over post` differently

Tags: feature-request, support, reputation, user-interface, timeline

This image shows reputation over posts:

[image: Reputation over posts]

This image shows reputation over time:

[image: Reputation over time]

There is no any problem with reputation shown over posts. But the reputation shown over time has been grouped by post: note the +30 for upvotes on "Send direct messages" and the +40 for upvotes on "Can I list my questions...". We can see last time on event group also which is shown in rep by time.

I would like these groups to be expandable so that I can see the individual events one after another. For example, I would like the reputation by time to be expandable to look like this, with all events listed individually in the order they happened. Which most probably contain mixture of different posts so that understand what rep changes occurred over time:

> +10   21:19   upvote   Send direct...
> +10   19:13   upvote   Send direct...
> +10   19:11   upvote   Send direct...
> +10   16:04   upvote   Can I list...
>  −2   14:10   downvote   Can I list...
> +10   09:38   upvote   Can I list...
>  −2   09:06   downvote   view my questions...
> +15   08:57   accept   Can I list...
> +10   08:55   upvote   Can I list...
> +10   08:54   upvote   Can I list...

Is it possible to show reputation over time like this?

If not, what is the disadvantage of my proposal, and what is the advantage of current system? Current distribution of `rep over time` is better fit under title `rep over events`

## Update:

I am not saying to remove current rep over time. I said that rename current system to `rep by event`. Because 50% people like to see current system. And 50%people like to see changes according to time. Last revision changed title and given different meaning which in result getting downvotes which had different meaning before posting question and having +3 upvotes. Sorry for that.

## Update for bounty:

I'd just expect the "time" view to show the events by time. It's not a big deal since the "post" view gives the chronological developments of events that relate to each other if you want to see them. The naming is just strange since "post" gives you detailed times for all events while the time stamps on "time" carry much less information. If what happened at a specific time long ago doesn't matter, what was the last time something specific happened on some day long ago surely matters even less (that's what "time" shows).

Comment: Uhh, I don't see what you're asking for.. Rep by time DOES show rep with time..

Comment: What I mean to show each change in reputation (+10,-2,-1,+15,etc) according to time(there may be mixing of rep changes of multiple posts) and not in group like post.

Comment: Rep by post is *meant* to be a concise "where did most of my rep that day come from?" view...if you want an expanded full-inclusive view, that's why there's the time/chronological view.  The post view is indeed meant to be very simple, very intentionally. Is it *possible*? sure, but it's the way it is by-design.

Comment: I don't have any queries about `rep by post`. I have concern about `rep by time`. Is it possible to view reputation over time not group by post? Show reputation of time according to event and not by grouping in post. I have given example what I mean.

Comment: @Somnath - we do group by event, we just rollup things that happen **in order with no events of another type in-between**, for example an `upvote, accept, upvote` on an answer are 3 events in the list, where `upvote, upvote, upvote, upvote, accept` would be only 2, to eliminate the noise of a lot of the same event in a row.

Comment: @Nick Craver: So it would be `rep over event` and not `rep over time`. Is it not possible to show according to my proposal? It will give clear view of reputation over time. i.e what's change in rep over(with) time and not according to type of event.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: you get the full gory details if you go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: But that is not aesthetic view. That page might not be visible long time. If we have data calculated according to my feature request then why not to show under `rep over time`. And current system can be shown as `rep over event`. So user can have both views.

Comment: @Somnath - You're basically asking when we roll up 30 upvotes **in a row, with nothing inbetween**...to *not* do that.  It's incredibly noisy, so no we wouldn't do that (that's *why* we roll up).  We don't hide or combine multiple types of events, we just show the same event repeated over and over with nothing in-between as a single row with the last date of that stream.  The alternative is **very** noisy for a lot of users, that's why I had to write code to do this in the first place...

Comment: `30 upvotes` in a row, which is good for listening. But 99% times it is false. There are chances to have events in between. I am not saying to remove current `rep by time`. I said that rename it to `rep by event` as it is showing according to event type last time with post and not all times. And show `rep by time` with changes in rep according to time. What's wrong to show if user want to see.

Comment: @NickCraver: What you describe is not what actually happens. See the OP's edit, which also reflects my experience. Events get grouped even if there are other events in between, breaking the chronological order.

Comment: @sth - That's the behavior for *recent* days, a more verbose view is applied to the last 3 days when you typically actively care about what's happening in more detail.  Beyond that we roll up.

Comment: @Nick: Why is the behavior for older days different? That rolled up view is less "by time" than what you get when you use the "post" ordering...

Comment: @sth - I don't follow, "by post" is completely rolled up **by post**, it's not chronological at all

Comment: @Nick: But you can expand those posts to see all the events of that post in order, chronologically. The "time" view is completely rolled up by event type, and you can't expand the entries to see the details. So the "post" view gives more information. If I have an entry for 10 upvotes at 23:47 in the "time" view, that only tells me there were 10 upvotes on that day.

Comment: @sth - That's correct *for old days*, why does it matter what happened *at a specific time* a long time ago?  The detail and clutter it brings just doesn't justify the extra UI elements there.

Comment: @Nick: I'd just expect the "time" view to show the events by time. It's not a big deal since the "post" view gives the chronological developments of events that relate to each other if you want to see them. The naming is just strange since "post" gives you detailed times for all events while the time stamps on "time" carry much less information. If *what happened at a specific time long ago* doesn't matter, *what was the last time something specific happened on some day long ago* surely matters even less (that's what "time" shows). tldr: "time" is useful, but not what I'd expect.

Comment: @Nick, it seems the sorted-by-time for the past 3 days is rolled up now too? (Totally fine with me!) Even more: for a post owner *new* votes seem to be rolled op in sequential order, like if votes are given to post A, A, A, B, A, then this shows descending by time as [post A +10, post B +10, post A +30](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h12l4.png). Then, after refreshing the page, hence when the votes are no longer considered "new" (or "unseen"), this changes to [post A +40, post B +10](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o9oYc.png)? And I assume other users will always see that latter view?