# Reputation Question

Tags: support, reputation

I was looking at the reputation on a user and noticed he/she received +110 for an upvote on an [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930301/how-to-prevent-user-from-selecting-and-copying-text-from-my-webpage/10930511#10930511) they had.  How does that happen?  I thought the most you could get is +10 per upvote.  Here is a screenshot of what I saw:

[image]

Comment: If you switch to the reputation by post tab, you see "+110/-4 13 events" for eleven up and two down votes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Identical lines [get combined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127954/show-reputation-over-time-and-over-post-differently#comment348674_127954), so the reputation page doesn't get cluttered.

The answer you mention simply got upvoted 11 times.

Likewise, the owner lost `4` rep because of two downvotes on the same answer.

To verify, you can check out the [timeline of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10930301/timeline) or [sort the user's reputation page by post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/truth?tab=reputation&sort=post)

And as quite usual on Stack Exchange, hover your mouse to see some details:

[image]

Comment: @Me, duh, stupid question.  I had a brain lapse.  Thanks for telling me the obvious.  I would delete this post, but since you already answer, I can't.  I'll go stand in the corner now.

Comment: @ToddGrover: If you display by post rather than time, it will show an expandable section for that post which will expand into 11 separate upvote events.